# window.location.href on Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

This does not work in Safari and Chrome:

```
$(".myButton").click(function(){
    window.location.href('www.blahblahblah.com');
});
```

what's the solution?

Comment: Is there any browser where this works? Why do you assume `location.href` is a function? Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

Comment: Saying "does not work" does not work. Please explain what behaviour you need, and exactly what you find it actually does. Do you get an error message? Nothing at all happening? The wrong URL being opened? Demons flying out of your nose?

Comment: @FelixKling surprisingly, it works in IE

Comment: @Jack: Ah, this one again... thanks!

Comment: really? `href` is a method in IE? O_o

Comment: @Raminson It's defined as a property actually, but (at least in IE9) can be magically called as a method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533867(v=vs.85).aspx#CommunityContentHeader

Answer (score 6, accepted):

window.location.href is not a function and therefor you cannot call it, you can however assign a value to it: (Also you should be using http:// when redirecting to another domain)

```
$(".myButton").click(function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://www.blahblahblah.com';
});
```

EDIT: Corrected my first statement and added the part about http://

Comment: Variables can contain functions as well. Your statement is not correct (actually, only `window` is a variable, `location` and `href` are properties (and if one wants to be pedantic, `window` is a property of the global object as well)). The only correct statement would be: `window.location.href` is not a function.

Comment: You also have to include `http://`, or it will try to navigate relative to the current page.

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar problem. In chrome, return false; solved the problem.

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this order?'))
{
location.href='delete_order.asp?id=20'; **return false;**} 
else 
{return false;}
```

The above code works in Chrome and IE9

Comment: Geez Louise...I've been pulling my hair out over this.  How did you figure this out?  Have you figured out the source of the problem?  Thank you!

Comment: PS...I understand the OP's question contained a basic Javascript error, but I found this post nevertheless, and return=false solved the problem I was having in Chrome only (WITH correct Javascript)...

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.assign('http://www.google.com')
```

is the function you're looking for.

It's the equivalent of

```
window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
```